# Run BeEF as a service in ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, services

I've been learning how to use BeEF recently for pentesting tasks and I was trying to set up a server in the cloud with BeEF installed in it running on the background, like a service, but I couldn't achieve it.

```
root@BeEF:~# sudo systemctl status beef
● beef.service - BeEF Framework
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/beef.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2024-02-16 03:50:53 UTC; 33s ago
    Process: 88622 ExecStart=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby /opt/beef/beef (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 88622 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 16 03:50:53 BeEF systemd[1]: Started BeEF Framework.
Feb 16 03:50:53 BeEF ruby[88622]: <internal:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require': cannot load such file -- m>
Feb 16 03:50:53 BeEF ruby[88622]:         from <internal:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
Feb 16 03:50:53 BeEF ruby[88622]:         from /opt/beef/core/loader.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
Feb 16 03:50:53 BeEF ruby[88622]:         from <internal:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
Feb 16 03:50:53 BeEF ruby[88622]:         from <internal:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
Feb 16 03:50:53 BeEF ruby[88622]:         from /opt/beef/beef:45:in `<main>'
Feb 16 03:50:53 BeEF systemd[1]: beef.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 16 03:50:53 BeEF systemd[1]: beef.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I was having other issues that after some hours I successfully resolve by my own. The first was that my Ruby was outdated, but I just installed `ruby-3.0.0` and beef worked fine (When ran by me).
When I begin to make the service file and then try to run it in the background it didn't work. I noticed that my ruby wasn't installed in `/usr/bin/ruby` but in a different directory: `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby` (One that I think `rvm` makes. I never used ruby by the way, so I don't know nothing about it).
Then, the error message changed, which is the one that I presented previously. I've been trying for a while to make it work but I don't know how. I think the service is not loading all the files required to work, but I just don't know which files I need to load in the service file.

This is what I've done:

```
# beef.service

[Unit]
Description=BeEF Framework
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
ExecStart=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/bin/ruby /opt/beef/beef

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Just as a note, if for any reason is important, I have beef (the cloned repository) installed in `/opt`, so when I want to call the application I just run `/opt/beef/beef`.

If anyone knows how to solve this or have any idea on how to approach this issue, I'll be very glad. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

BeFF isn't correctly installed on your system.

BeFF come with its own systemd service `beef-xss.service`, the sytemd file service should be found under `/usr/lib/systemd/system/beef-xss.service`

To check the service status :

```
beef-xss
systemctl status beef-xss
```

[See beef on gitlab](https://gitlab.com/kalilinux/packages/beef-xss/-/tree/kali/master/debian?ref_type=heads)